# Google Java OAuth2.0 - Refresh token missing on first code exhange flow

Tags: java, oauth-2.0, google-api-java-client

I am setting up Google AUth2.0 for my API and need to store the refresh token and access token together for later usage.

However, it seems that I cannot retrieve the refresh token...

```
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(TRANSPORT,
        JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, ProjectsApi.SCOPES)
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .setApprovalPrompt("force")
                .build();

GoogleTokenResponse response = flow
        .newTokenRequest(code)
        .setRedirectUri(clientSecrets.getDetails().getRedirectUris().get(0))
        .execute();

String accessToken = response.getAccessToken();
String refreshToken = response.getRefreshToken();

System.out.println(accessToken); // ya29. ...
System.out.println(refreshToken); // null
```

Here is the part where I get the tokens out of the request. The user is prompted to allow (or deny) access to his Cloud Storage data correctly.

However, the returned data never contains the refresh token...

I have tried (as I read on the internet similar issues) to change the approval prompt to `consent` or `force` without success. I have en tried to regenerate new credentials and test it out of the blue.

Has anyone insights into how this should be done ?

Thanks in advance!